# Tunnels to the same port number

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have an application that connects to several hosts on the same port:

```
a.protected:123
b.protected:123
```

I don't have direct access to either of them, but I can make a ssh tunnel (through `x.accessible`).

Should the ports have been distinct, I could have make the tunnel to the same port number:

```
ssh -f me@x.accessible -L 123:a.protected:123 -N
```

And then I would have added a.protected as an alias to localhost, in `/etc/hosts`

But given that more hosts use the same port number, what are my options?
How can I use tunnels to get the application to connect to them, without changing the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options. Either use different source addresses or use a socks proxy.

### Different source addresses

Your `lo` interface is configured as `127.0.0.1/8`, i.e. all addresses starting with 127 do belong to the current host.

The syntax for your tunnel is

```
-L [bind_address:] port:host:hostport
```

Therefore you can use something like:

```
ssh -L 127.1.0.1:123:a.protected:123 -L 127.1.0.2:123:b.protected:123
```

Now let a.protected resolve to 127.1.0.1:123 and b.protected resolve to 127.1.0.2.

### Using a socks proxy

```
ssh -D 1080
```

This will start a local socks proxy on port `1080`. All connection will resolve and connect on the other end of the tunnel.

If you application supports socks proxies just configure it. Otherwise you can use `tsocks` to use the proxy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy and transparent way to use one port for two connections simultaneously.

From my point easy and right way is to create tunnels on different local ports:

```
ssh -f me@x.accessible -L 123:a.protected:123 -N
ssh -f me@x.accessible -L 123:a.protected:124 -N
```

So the first connection will be available via port 123 and the second one vie port 124.

ps. remember, that you need a root permissions to use port under 1024.